# Tensorflow: ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, importerror

I am on Linux Kubuntu 14.4 and try to install

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.0.0
```

which seems to works. `import tensorflow as tf` also work in my python code. But then I call one of my functions in one of my python modules (same project) and there, when calling `import tensorflow as tf`, I get the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

The link https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error is dead and I found https://github.com/benoitsteiner/tensorflow-opencl/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md but I don't quite see how this helps me.

Comment: Is it possible that the python modules which fails to run, are running from tensorflow source directory?

Comment: I was able to solve it. I am not sure how though. I restarted stuff a couple of times, renamed some of my files. Now it works.